# Separator in Android Action bar is not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, styles, android-actionbar

I have implemented the Actionbar in android successfully but i am getting one problem in that. I have used separator in it but somehow my separator is not visible.

Here is the Layout file and styles:-

XML File :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <RelativeLayout style="@style/TitleBar" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/homebtn"
            style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="Home"
            android:onClick="onClickHome"
            android:src="@drawable/title_home" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            style="@style/TitleBarSeparator"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/homebtn"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logos"
            style="@style/TitleBarLogo"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/separator"
            android:contentDescription="Logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Styles :-**

```
    <style name="TitleBar">
        <item name="android:id">@id/titlebar</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/title_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarLogo">
        <item name="android:id">@id/title_logo</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarAction">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/title_button</item>
    </style>

<style name="TitleBarSeparator">
        <item name="android:layout_width">1px</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/title_separator</item>
    </style>
```

Here is the snapshot.

[image]

& what i want is like this...[image]

Comment: Don't you think your separator is left of your home image ?

Comment: How can be it on left side? My home button is in left side and i want separator to right of it...

Comment: sorry I misunderstood.Try by increasing width 1px to 5px. and provide id to separator.

Comment: use image view as a seperator with white color

Comment: i have used the white color....

Comment: in TitleBarSeperator i have defined the color...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you have set layout_height to wrap_content instead of fill_parent ?